# How to remove or edit MPAndroidChart - StackedBarChart - entries?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

My stacked bar chart in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) works very well but I'm trying to remove or edit the values inside the bars. But I can't find any code which makes sense to modify.

[image]

I don't think that my code is very helpful, but here it is...

```
private void initStackedBarChartStuff() {
    mMonths = dfs.getShortMonths();
    mChart = (BarChart) mContext.findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

    mChart.setDescription("");

// if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
// drawn
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(30);

// scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);

    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);

// change the position of the y-labels
    YAxis yLabels = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    yLabels.setValueFormatter(new MyYAxisValueFormatter());
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);

    XAxis xLabels = mChart.getXAxis();
    xLabels.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);

    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_RIGHT);
    l.setFormSize(8f);
    l.setFormToTextSpace(4f);
    l.setXEntrySpace(6f);

// mChart.setDrawLegend(false);
}
```

fill the stackedBarChart

```
private void fillStackedBarChart(Vector drawingData, Vector drawingIntervall) {
    if (drawingData == null || drawingData == null)
      return;

    int anzBdata = dataSizes[1];
    int intervall = globalIntervall;
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();


//  Strings über die Blöcke schreiben   ###########################################
    {
      long zeit = 0;
      String[] months = new String[12];
      String[] days = new String[7];
      boolean einmal = true;

      for (int i = 0; i < drawingIntervall.size(); i++)
        zeit += ((Long) drawingIntervall.get(i)).longValue();

      if (bigData) //  > 2 Jahre
        months = null;
      else if (zeit > 31623000) //  > 1 Jahre
        months = dfs.getShortMonths();
      else
        months = dfs.getMonths();
      days = dfs.getWeekdays();


      for (int i = 0; i < drawingData.size(); i++) {
        long[] pack = (long[]) drawingData.get(i);
        String s = "";

        //        Sonderfall !! In Monatsansicht den Monat dazu schreiben
        if ((einmal) && (intervall == 2)) {
          if (etStart.getText().toString().trim().startsWith("01.")) {
            Calendar calE = convStringToDate(etEnd.getText().toString().trim(), true, true);
            int jahr = calE.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int monat = calE.get(Calendar.MONTH);

            Calendar calX = myGetInstance();
            calX.set(Calendar.YEAR, jahr);
            calX.set(Calendar.MONTH, monat);
            calX = getLastDayOfMonth(calX);

            if (calE.getTimeInMillis() == calX.getTimeInMillis()) {
              einmal = false;
              s = months[calE.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
            }
          }
        }

        switch (intervall) {
          case 0:
            s += df.format(convMilliToDate(pack[0] * 1000, false, false).getTime());
            break;

          case 1:
            s += convMilliToString(pack[0] * 1000);
            break;

          case 2:
            s += "KW " + convMilliToDate(pack[0] * 1000, false,     false).get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            break;

          case 3:
            if (bigData)
              s += convMilliToDate(pack[0] * 1000, false,     false).get(Calendar.YEAR) + "";
            else
              s += months[convMilliToDate(pack[0] * 1000, false, false).get(Calendar.MONTH)];
            break;
        }

        xVals.add(s);
      }
    }


    //   nun alle Balken/Blöcke zeichnen       ##########################################
    {
//      1 Y-Wert entspricht z.B. 1 Tag, o. 1 Woche,... jeder Y-Wert hat so viele floats wie B-Daten vorhanden sind   ###########################################
      ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

      for (int i = 0; i < drawingData.size(); i++) {
        long[] pack = (long[]) drawingData.get(i);
        long intervallSek = ((Long) drawingIntervall.get(i)).longValue()     + 1;
        long pastSek = 0;
        float[] f = new float[anzBdata + 1];
        int b = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < pack.length; j++) {
          if ((j >= dataSizes[0]) && (j <= (anzBdata - 1 + dataSizes[0]))) {
        f[b++] = pack[j];
        pastSek += pack[j];
      }
    }
        f[b++] = intervallSek - pastSek;  //  zeichnet einen Block indem "keine Daten" aufgezeichnet wurden. (wenn Maschine ohne Strom o.ä.)
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(f, i));
      }

//      BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Statistics Business Data");
      BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");
      set1.setColors(getColors());
      set1.setStackLabels(barChartLegend);

      ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
      dataSets.add(set1);

      BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
      data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());

      mChart.setData(data);
      mChart.invalidate();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not really pretty, may somone else find a better one...

The class BarChart extends from BarLineChartBase. There is a line in BarLineChartBase which can be annotated or removed to get the desired solution.

```
mRenderer.drawValues(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways:

- Use the [ValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) to custom format your values (edit or remove)
- Use `dataSet.setDrawValues(false)` to completely remove all values